# Why are some PHP extensions disabled by default in a XAMPP server?

Tags: php, xampp

There are a few PHP extensions (such as cURL) that are disabled by default in a XAMPP server.

What is the reason for that?

Is it mostly performance that's taken into consideration, is it security or is it something else?

Comment: i guess it is to show windows users that they better use linux :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is because of performance reasons, to only load the necessary modules required by the user. It comes with the extensions installed because there is a relatively big likelihood the user would need the extension, but do not impose it upon them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say all of the above, with performance being the first reason. Why waste the time and memory to initialize something that you might never use?